# Make a sticky nested navbar

Tags: html, css, grid, sticky

I'm trying to make a sticky navbar nested with a split header using the grid system, but the sticky feature doesn't work. I tried all the solutions on the internet like using align-items and align-self to no avail, the code below explains everything

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  height: 1000rem;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F00;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'logo social' 'navbar navbar';
  padding: .5rem;
}
header .logo {
  padding: .5rem;
  grid-area: logo;
}
header .social {
  padding: .5rem;
  display: flex;
  grid-area: social;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
header .social div {
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-inline-end: .5rem;
}
header nav {
  padding: .5rem;
  grid-area: navbar;
  background-color: #00F;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
  padding: .5rem;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below CSS to make header sticky :

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    height: 1000rem;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F00;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    'logo social'
    'navbar navbar';
    padding: .5rem;
    position: fixed;
}
header .logo {
    padding: .5rem;
    grid-area: logo;
}
header .social {
    padding: .5rem;
    display: flex;
    grid-area: social;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
header .social div {
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-inline-end: .5rem;
}
header nav {
    padding: .5rem;
    grid-area: navbar;
    background-color: #00F;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
header nav ul {
    display: flex;
}
header nav ul li {
    padding: .5rem;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: But I do not want to make the header fixed